# MacBook Pro SSD boot issues

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

So I have a MacBook Pro (Late '12), has run seamlessly with all OSes that I have put on it, (not to say that this problem is due to the OS).
(I'm trying to be as detailed as possible so bear with me.)
 (Side note: I posted this exact same question in the Apple discussions but no one could answer my question.)
The other day I simply opened up Finder and went to my movies folder which is housed on my 2TB Time Capsule that I connect to wirelessly. After taking the usual 5 seconds or so to pull up this particular folder, Finder stops responding so I do what any tech-savvy person does: pull up Terminal to kill Finder's process. Normally Terminal will login as your user, this time however, it somehow gets stuck on the login part, simply displaying 'login:'. Won't let me type or anything. I shut down the MBP and boot it up to find a flashing folder with a question mark on it. Okay, that's fine. Plug in an external with OS X Utilities and Recovery on it, attempt to verify my internal SSD which fails, giving me

> error code 8

After doing this for some time I assume there's something wrong with the partition table, and at this point I don't care if I lose my documents I just want my SSD bootable again. I go into another external that I have with Yosemite on it, and partition my internal into two partions: DJ OS (I DJ as well) and Mac OS. I try to install Yosemite on to DJ OS but to no avail.
I go back to my 2nd external and run `fsck_hfs -fy /dev/disk0s2`
I am a CECS major (Freshman) so I usually know what I'm doing, but hard drives and their well-being is nooot my thing, so this just perplexed me:

```
Sams-MacBook-Pro:/ user$ sudo fsck_hfs -fy /dev/disk0s2  
** /dev/rdisk0s2 (NO WRITE)  
   Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-285).  
** Verifying volume when it is mounted with write access.  
fsck_hfs: pread(5, 0x7fab2c00f200, 114176, 6542336): Input/output error  
   Journal need to be replayed but volume is read-only  
** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.  
   The volume name is DJ OS  
** Checking extents overflow file.  
** Checking catalog file.  
** Checking multi-linked files.  
** Checking catalog hierarchy.  
** Checking extended attributes file.  
** The volume DJ OS could not be verified completely.  
Sams-MacBook-Pro:/ user$ sudo fsck_hfs -fy /dev/disk0s2  
** /dev/rdisk0s2 (NO WRITE)  
   Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-285).  
** Verifying volume when it is mounted with write access.  
fsck_hfs: pread(5, 0x7fefdb014200, 105984, 6657024): Input/output error  
   Journal need to be replayed but volume is read-only  
** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.  
   The volume name is DJ OS  
** Checking extents overflow file.  
** Checking catalog file.  
   Incorrect number of thread records  
(4, 3)  
   Invalid leaf record count  
   (It should be 162 instead of 158)  
** Checking multi-linked files.  
** Checking catalog hierarchy.  
** Checking extended attributes file.  
** Checking volume bitmap.  
   Volume bitmap needs minor repair for under-allocation  
** Checking volume information.  
   Invalid volume file count  
   (It should be 59 instead of 63)  
   Invalid volume free block count  
   (It should be 26801207 instead of 26801165)  
   Volume header needs minor repair  
(2, 0)  
** The volume DJ OS was found corrupt and needs to be repaired.
```

After this, just to be sure, I go back to DU and run the repair. This is what I get:

```
Verify and Repair volume “DJ OS”
Repairing file system.
Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
Checking extents overflow file.
The volume DJ OS could not be verified completely.
File system check exit code is 8.
Updating boot support partitions for the volume as required.
Error: Disk Utility can’t repair this disk.
Back up as many of your files as possible, reformat the disk, and restore your backed-up files.
```

What concerns me is that is says it is corrupt and needs to be repaired, my problem is that every time I repair it in Disk Utility I get an error code and it tells me it can't repair it. So all in all, I have a corrupt internal SSD, which refuses to be repaired by Disk Utility. Please help!!

Additional information on my internal drive:

```
APPLE SSD SM256E:
  Capacity: 251 GB (251,000,193,024 bytes)
  Model: APPLE SSD SM256E                       
  Revision: CXM07A1Q
  Serial Number: S0X7NYACB01671     
  Native Command Queuing: Yes
  Queue Depth: 32
  Removable Media: No
  Detachable Drive: No
  BSD Name: disk0
  Medium Type: Solid State
  TRIM Support: Yes
  Partition Map Type: GPT (GUID Partition Table)
  S.M.A.R.T. status: Verified
  Volumes:
EFI:
  Capacity: 209.7 MB (209,715,200 bytes)
  BSD Name: disk0s1
  Content: EFI
  Volume UUID: 0E239BC6-F960-3107-89CF-1C97F78BB46B
DJ OS:
  Capacity: 110 GB (110,000,001,024 bytes)
  Available: 109.78 GB (109,777,743,872 bytes)
  Writable: Yes
  File System: Journaled HFS+
  BSD Name: disk0s2
  Mount Point: /Volumes/DJ OS
  Content: Apple_HFS
  Volume UUID: 75A5AFC8-4781-332E-AFB8-90F35AE351C8
Mac OS:
  Capacity: 140.52 GB (140,522,000,384 bytes)
  Available: 135.04 GB (135,036,993,536 bytes)
  Writable: Yes
  File System: Journaled HFS+
  BSD Name: disk0s3
  Mount Point: /Volumes/Mac OS
  Content: Apple_HFS
  Volume UUID: 8DC169A0-B2C8-390D-8F3C-F43EB921874F
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? I just bought a brand new SSD Drive to replace one that I think failed. When trying to install 10.10.4 from a USB drive, I get the same errors you were getting.

Answer (score 1):

You state that you have a Time Capsule, so that would imply that you have current backups. If you have a current, complete backup of the system, the easiest solution here is to boot to recovery mode, open Disk Utility and erase the partition. With a fresh file system in place, exit Disk Utility and proceed to restore from the TC backup.

Note: If you have successfully backed up corrupted files, you will also successfully restore them. If the system continues to exhibit strange behaviour even when DU indicates no file system problems and hardware test is clear, you'll probably want to consider a fresh OS install and a profile/data/apps migration. (Within the last week, I went through this exact scenario courtesy of a corruption in the encrypted volume that made it unbootable.)

Comment: I'm sorry I should have specified this, but I do not use the TC for backups. I use it for storing all of my multimedia files due to my internal's small store capacity.

Comment: If you don't have a backup, there's not much help to offer here. Backups are the essential component in a recovery strategy.

Comment: I'm not looking to recover any data at this point, I just want to be able to clean up the drive so that I can install an OS onto it without getting I/O errors.